# How can I get all possible string literals of Array<>

Tags: typescript

Is something like this possible in TypeScript?

```
const bla: Array<'Value1' | 'Value2' | 'Value3'> = [];
// list all possible values: 'Value1' | 'Value2' | 'Value3' like with below enum

enum Bla1 {
  Value1 = 'Value1',
  Value2 = 'Value2',
  Value3 = 'Value3'
}

console.log(Object.keys(Bla1));
// outputs: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
```

If I have enum it's possible, but I want to avoid enum.

Comment: are you okay with using enum like javascript object instead? Or do you want to get the array type from `type Literal = "Value1" | "Value2" ...` ?. I'm currently not sure what exactly you expect, please include some details

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Without using any kind of runtime value (such as an enum) it is not possible to somehow transfer `types` to runtime values like a string array in your case.

Types only exist at compile time!

---

Note, the only reason why things like `Object.keys(Enum);` work is that enums are compiled to JavaScript objects.

```
var Bla1;
(function (Bla1) {
    Bla1["Value1"] = "Value1";
    Bla1["Value2"] = "Value2";
    Bla1["Value3"] = "Value3";
})(Bla1 || (Bla1 = {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the enum and then use it to derive the type for your array:

```js
enum Bla1 {
  Value1 = 'Value1',
  Value2 = 'Value2',
  Value3 = 'Value3'
}

const bla: Array<`${Bla1}`> = [];
bla.push('Value1');
bla.push('foo'); // error

console.log(Object.keys(Bla1));
```

You still must define the enum, but you don't need to fill the array with enum values. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.